# Understanding likelihood vs conditional joint pdf

Tags: bayesian, likelihood, definition

My course notes (3rd-year module in Bayesian Statistics, unpublished) have a paragraph,

> **Gaussian data with  known variance**
>
> Suppose we have $\textbf{x}=\{x_1,\dots,x_n\}$ iid given $\theta$ and $\sigma^2$ as N$(x_i\,|\,\theta,\sigma^2)$, and assume $\theta$ unknown but $\sigma^2$ known. Given these data you are interested in the unknown expected value $\theta$. We can write down the likelihood function as $$f(\textbf{x}\,|\,\theta)\propto\prod_{i=1}^n\sqrt{\frac{1}{2\pi\sigma^2}}\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}(x_i-\theta)^2\right).$$

Would I be right in thinking that calling $f$ "the likelihood function" is actually an abuse of notation/terminology (albeit a conventional one), and that it would be more accurate to say the following?

> We can write down the likelihood function as $$\mathcal{L}(\theta\,|\,\textbf{x})\propto f(\textbf{x}\,|\,\theta)=\prod_{i=1}^n\sqrt{\frac{1}{2\pi\sigma^2}}\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}(x_i-\theta)^2\right),$$
> where $f(\textbf{x}\,|\,\theta)$ is the joint pdf of the data $\textbf{x}$ conditional on $\theta$.

**ETA:** I asked a related [question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/588574/l-thetax-fx-theta-vs-l-thetax-propto-fx-theta) a while ago, and accepted an [answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/588623/285236). I've spent most of today staring at the image included in that answer.
[image]

Comment: Still, the density of the data could be proportional to the rhs if, e.g., the data is produced in an ordered way, with $x_1<x_2<\cdots$.

Comment: I would agree calling $f$ a likelihood is an abuse of terminology.  It's also bizarre, most obviously it's a density function, but then the "propto" symbol is there, but they have included the normalizing constant. Much easier to write $f(x|\theta) \propto \exp(c (x_i - \theta) ^2) $

Comment: @AdamO Thanks, that's a relief to have confirmed. The proportionality you mention is actually added as a further step in the notes, which I omitted from my quote, but the notes do as quoted use the $\propto$ sign for the first step, between $f$ and the product with the proportionality constant.

Comment: @Xi'an I'm afraid I don't understand. How does the ordering of the data affect the equality of the joint pdf to the product of the individual pdfs?

Comment: The density of the ordered sample is $n!$ times the density of the unordered one.