# comparing 2 likelihood values

Tags: density-function, likelihood

Are likelihood values (density values) comparable across different types of distributions?

For example, if you have a data point that has a likelihood value of .05 under a normal distribution and .025 under a student T distribution, the .05 and .025 are comparable?

In that case, that data point is twice as likely to come from the normal distribution  given its parameter values vs. the T distribution given its parameters?

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! Could you please say what exactly you mean that a point is twice as “likely”? For better or for worse, “likelihood” in formal probability theory and mathematical statistics has a specific meaning that isn’t perfectly aligned with the colloquial English use of the word.

Comment: i just mean if they are on the same scale then .05 is 2 times .025 and since the values indicate the likelihood of observing the data it’s 2times as likely

Comment: But what do you mean by “likely”?

Comment: the probability of the the observed data given the parameters  P(X = x | θ)

Comment: This is a good example of why this kind of back-and-forth clarification in the comments is useful, as likelihood is not quite a probability and can exceed one. Could you please clarify further what you want to know and the context where it has arisen?

Comment: “The likelihood is the probability that a particular outcome 
x is observed when the true value of the parameter is 
θ” https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Likelihood_function

Comment: That quote is an incorrect statement. If nothing else, likelihood can exceed one, while probability cannot.

Comment: https://hea-www.harvard.edu/AstroStat/aas227_2016/lecture1_Robinson.pdf  see slide 8 “it’s the probability the parameter value would yield the observed data”  what is your definition?

Comment: Likelihood can exceed one. Thus, likelihood is not probability.

Comment: https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~10315/notes/10315_S23_Notes_MLE_draft.pdf pg 3

Comment: it’s commonly understood to be density which the question noted “(density values)”

Comment: Jhn5v78, the example in the notes you linked to refers to discrete distributions (binomial, etc). For continuous distributions such as normal, you can turn densities into probabilities by taking the integral. This gives the probability that the data fall into the interval you integrated over; A density twice as large for distribution 1 as for distribution 2 on that interval indeed means data being twice as likely. By likelihood in statistics we understand a function of parameters given the data. This is not to be understood as probability of the parameter.

Comment: hi ute, you can turn densities into probability if you take the integral of the pdf since in a pdf the parameter is not fixed but here i am asking about likelihoods and if you take the integral of likelihood density values it will likely not equal 1 so it is not a probability. see slide 7 of harvard. the likelihood needs a normalization term. i ask are 2 (unnormalized) density values from different distributions comparable

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be asking two different questions. The first one, about comparability, is a duplicate of [Likelihood comparable across different distributions](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/345069/likelihood-comparable-across-different-distributions)

Then you say:

> In that case, that data point is twice as likely to come from the normal distribution given its parameter values vs. the T distribution given its parameters?

You cannot conclude that! Likelihood values come from a probability model, yes, but they cannot therefore itself be interpreted as probabilities (neither as probability densities). The wording of your conclusion has a bayesian flavour, and such a conclusion would require some full bayesian model, with priors.