# AIC and nested models

Tags: aic, nested-models

There is a related question [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/116935/comparing-non-nested-models-with-aic) but two highly upvoted answers there don't seem to agree with each other, and in any case I wanted to take a different tack.

Is AIC useful for comparing:

1. non-nested models only.
2. nested models only.
3. either non-nested or nested models.

Why/Why not?

Comment: Related question [Prerequisites for AIC model comparison](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/48714/prerequisites-for-aic-model-comparison).

Comment: Given the diametrically opposed views expressed in the cited sources perhaps best to avoid using AIC for non-nested. There are several methods devised for non-nested methods and if you use R they are packaged in lmtest